# DioError [DioErrorType.response]: Http status error [504]

Tags: flutter, api, dart, dio

There's an error in my flutter app `DioError [DioErrorType.response]: Http status error [504]` I don't know why it shows 504 as what I know before, `504` means `Gateway Timeout`, why it took a long time to respond eventhough it shows the correct response in postman. It ended up with showing "error" in my app's user interface (UI) and my console is look like this:

```
I/flutter (16822): DioError [DioErrorType.response]: Http status error [504]
I/flutter (16822): Source stack:
I/flutter (16822): #0      DioMixin.fetch (package:dio/src/dio_mixin.dart:488:35)
I/flutter (16822): #1      DioMixin.request (package:dio/src/dio_mixin.dart:483:12)
I/flutter (16822): #2      DioMixin.get (package:dio/src/dio_mixin.dart:61:12)
I/flutter (16822): #3      ApiWrapper.request (package:eoffice/utils/networks/ApiWrapper.dart:66:38)
I/flutter (16822): <asynchronous suspension>
I/flutter (16822): #4      SimpegService.apiRequest (package:eoffice/utils/networks/constans/SimpegService.dart:34:16)
I/flutter (16822): <asynchronous suspension>
I/flutter (16822): #5      LeaveListRepository.fetchResponse (package:eoffice/modules/home/views/widgets/Dashboard/DashboardApp/Leave/LeaveList/repositories/LeaveListRepository.dart:14:9)
I/flutter (16822): <asynchronous suspension>
I/flutter (16822): #6      LeaveListBloc.fetchResponse (package:eoffice/modules/home/views/widgets/Dashboard/DashboardApp/Leave/LeaveList/blocs/LeaveListBloc.dart:33:11)
I/flutter (16822): <asynchronous suspension>
D/EGL_emulation(16822): app_time_stats: avg=62.44ms min=6.19ms max=130.16ms count=15
I/flutter (16822): DioError [DioErrorType.response]: Http status error [504]
I/flutter (16822): Source stack:
I/flutter (16822): #0      DioMixin.fetch (package:dio/src/dio_mixin.dart:488:35)
I/flutter (16822): #1      DioMixin.request (package:dio/src/dio_mixin.dart:483:12)
I/flutter (16822): #2      DioMixin.get (package:dio/src/dio_mixin.dart:61:12)
I/flutter (16822): #3      ApiWrapper.request (package:eoffice/utils/networks/ApiWrapper.dart:66:38)
I/flutter (16822): <asynchronous suspension>
I/flutter (16822): #4      SimpegService.apiRequest (package:eoffice/utils/networks/constans/SimpegService.dart:34:16)
I/flutter (16822): <asynchronous suspension>
I/flutter (16822): #5      LeaveListRepository.fetchResponse (package:eoffice/modules/home/views/widgets/Dashboard/DashboardApp/Leave/LeaveList/repositories/LeaveListRepository.dart:14:9)
I/flutter (16822): <asynchronous suspension>
I/flutter (16822): #6      LeaveListBloc.fetchResponse (package:eoffice/modules/home/views/widgets/Dashboard/DashboardApp/Leave/LeaveList/blocs/LeaveListBloc.dart:33:11)
I/flutter (16822): <asynchronous suspension>
```

Answer (score 0):

are you using a device or emulator? if emulator, when you fetch you must use 10.0.2.2 as localhost. For device use the ip4 in cmd ipconfig.

Comment: hello im already fix it, it's actually because i put the wrong paramater on the bloc file